# Different figures on different computers

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, virtualenv

These figures are produced completely in different format (Figure A - incorrect figure; Figure B - correct figure; only color is different but code is the same). The code is run on different machines. Both use Anaconda and Figure A is generated on a machine which has freshly installed Anaconda (hence later versions). Correct Figure B is generated with Jupyter Notebook, funnily enough - if Spyder is used the figure on the same machine would suddenly start producing Figure A. I'm sure the difference must be related to dependencies. Anaconda uses `(base)` virtual environment in both cases, so there are no multiple environments - but why Jupyter Notebook and Spyder would produce different results? I have tried two methods, both of which was unsuccessful:

1. Exported libraries to YML file from a machine which generates correct figure to create Anaconda virtual environment, then tried to install it on the other computer, but it gave some errors which I assumed could be due to some versions not being available anymore.

`conda env create --name newenv --file exported.yml`

Error message following:
[image]

2. Created a fresh Python 3.6.4 in a virtualenv which current Anaconda uses and installed the same matplotlib==2.2.2 in the new virtualenv, however the figures are still incorrect.

I'm starting to think that we may need to start using Docker, but it's a relatively small task and I'm not even sure how to replicate my computer's older version Anaconda (which is probably just about a year old). Is it also possible, that even both use matplotlib 2.2.2, but there are bits which may behave different on the canvas. If so, how would I influence both so they behave the same? This question is about replicating the same behaviour on one Anaconda (Jupyter Notebook) to be the same as the other when producing figures.

**Figure A**
[image]

**Figure B**
[image]

Comment: maybe `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in the old environment and then `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the new? Let me know if it does the trick

Comment: Anaconda has about 200 libraries after exported to `requirements.txt` - i think it will be quite tricky to install them all with simple `pip` due to dependencies and libraries are just sorted alphabetically - nevertheless i tried your suggestion and second library failed! `anaconda-client==1.6.9`....I really hope there is an easier way than resolving all 200 libraries!

Comment: No worries! I assumed you were using a `venv` hence the pip suggestion 
The issue is certainly around library versions, so hopefully you will find a way to resolve

Comment: No doubt the library versions are different.  But without seeing the code, its hard to tell whats changed.  Odds are there is a back-compatible way to get the same figure in each env.

Comment: Thanks both, I'm hoping someone has a suggestion how to resolve the conflict around `mkl` and `pysal`, should I comment out one of them, if so which one is not needed?

Comment: Note that the key is really to have the exact same matplotlib version. All other 199 packages shouldn't matter. Also feel free to provide a [mcve] with a `print(matplotlib.__version__)` to allow people to reproduce the problem.

Comment: All this time the answer was under my nose! Since I was using Anaconda (I believed what I saw with `pip freeze` on Anaconda Prompt that matplotlib version was `2.2.2`, but after checking `matplotlib.__version__` just in case, Jupyter Notebook uses `matplotlib==1.5.3` to my shock! I genuinely believed that matplotlib versions are the same but dependency versions must be different. Thanks a lot!